# How to correctly use "frontespizio" package

Tags: thesis, frontespizio

I'm an italian guy and I'm trying to get a frontispiece for my thesis using the `frontespizio` package.

First of all, I have to admit that my TeX knowledge is limited. I was able to add that package to my MikTeX database (I followed some tips online), so that my TeX editor could recognize it.

However, the command `\begin{frontespizio}` is still not being recognized.
Can someone suggest me what I need to do for solving this problem?

Using the example given in tutorial, I typed this

```
\documentclass[a4paper,titlepage]{book}

\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{frontespizio}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frontespizio}
        \Istituzione{Universit\‘a di Pisa}
        \Facolta{Ingegneria}
        \Corso{Corso di Laurea}
        \Annoaccademico{2014--2015}
        \Titoletto{Tesi di laurea}
        \Titolo{000000}
        \Candidato[PP999999]{Paperon de’ Paperoni}
        \Relatore{Giovanni Episcopo}
        \Relatore{Pippo Cluvio}
        \Correlatore{Ugo Frogio}
        \Correlatore{Ubaldo Kutuzu}
    \end{frontespizio}
\end{document}
```

but blank page appears compiling the commands and `frontespizio` tags are red highlighted.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I should be able to help, for obvious reasons, but, please, add a minimal example of a document using the package.

Comment: Note that it should be ``Universit\`a``, not `Universit\’a` as you typed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are 3 required passages:

1. Compile your main file (let's call it `test.tex`).
2. Find and compile `test-frn.tex`. It should be in the same folder.
3. Go back and recompile `test.tex`.

[image]

Comment: Note that it's not necessary to always do these steps, but only if the frontispiece has changed.

Comment: Thanks egreg and Alenanno for you help! I resolved my problem!